# Ubuntu 15.10 on MacBook Pro 1,1 without Grub?

Tags: boot, uefi, macbook

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 on MacBook Pro 1,1 (very old), and I use rEFInd to boot. Everything works fine with Grub. In rEFInd there is a option to boot into Ubuntu skipping Grub. It works only with **nomodeset** parameter, and graphics are sluggish.

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
$ VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV530/M56-P [Mobility Radeon X1600] [1002:71c5]
```

If I try to boot without **nomodeset**, system freezes immediately after loading radeon driver. This is the last output before freezing:

```
fb: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA
```

Is it possible to load the driver after Ubuntu boots? Or is there other way to boot without Grub?